# How to "re-arrange" the legend in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot with several lines representing different columns of data, the legend is being arrange as a vertical column, but I want to place it at the bottom of the chart and arrange the keys horizontally, can it be done? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It does now.  Just use:

```
opts(legend.position="bottom", legend.direction="horizontal")
```

Since version 0.9.2, `opts` has been [replaced](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/theme.html) by `theme`:

```
theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.direction = "horizontal")
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not in the current implementation of ggplot2. Hadley has it on his to-do I think :-)

You can always position the legend manually

```
opts(legend.position=c(0.5,0.5))
```

but the keys stays vertical :-/